# Mvc 3 posting content type application/json, action method arguments loose mapping?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an interesting situation that has me stumped. 
It seems that posting `appliction/json` content type makes the basic routing engine unable to bind action method arguments.

Using the default route:

```
Routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

I have an action method that looks like this:

```
//Controller name: TestController
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveItem(int id, JsonDto dto)
{
  // if content type of the request is application/json id = 0, JsonDto is populated
  // if content type of the request is application/x-www-form-urlencode id = 1
}
```

I am posting to this url `/Test/SaveItem/1` + the json object.

The reason that I need to `id` and the `JsonDto` is that the `id` argument references the parent object that the `JsonDto` object need to releate to.

I suppose I could change the dto to contain the parent id as a property and work around this whole problem.

It just strikes me as strange that the `id` argument does not get populated when I post a `application/json` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my problem.

The problem is that the Json data that is being posted to the action method includes an `Id`

property, in addition to the `id` route value from the default route.  So when binding the JSON

object, its `Id` property wins over the route value in the URL.  So to tweak Darin's example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveItem", new { id = 123 })',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "Id": 456
        }),
        success: function (result) {
            // TODO: handle the results
        }
    });
</script>
```

When the action method exectures, the `int id` argument contains 456 and not 123 as I

(apparently mistakenly) expected.

So the workaround for me was to change my default route to:

```
Routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{urlId}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", urlId = UrlParameter.Optional } // 
);
```

Renaming the default `id` route parameter to `urlId` and updating my action methods solved the

conflict for me.

Answer (score 4):

OK, you haven't shown how you are calling this action so we can only be guessing here. Here's an example of something that works perfectly fine for me and gets everything populated as expected in the `SaveItem` method:

Model:

```
public class JsonDto
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveItem(int id, JsonDto dto)
    {
        return Content("success", "text/plain");
    }
}
```

Index View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SaveItem", new { id = 123 })',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            foo: 'bar'
        }),
        success: function (result) {
            // TODO: handle the results
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I am calling the method as a REST request, in essence a WebRequest to the /Home/SaveItem/123 with the content type set as application/json and the entity body set as the json string.  I will try removing the OAuth security on my endpoint to see if I can execute the example from a jquery ajax call as you are in your response to see if it works.

Comment: Interesting, so this works from the client side, but not through the webrequest.. I must not be creating the correct type of request somehow.