# Route broken under MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have this route that worked before we upgraded our application to MVC3:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Versioned API with Controller, ID, subentity",
  "api/{version}/{controller}/{id}/{subentity}/",
  new { controller = "API", action = "Index" },
  new { id = @"\d+", subentity = "serviceitem|accessitem" }
),
```

I'm attempting to hit this route with a POST to the following url:

```
/api/1.0/items/3/serviceitem
```

My controller method has this signature:

```
[ActionName("Index"), AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult CreateServiceItem(int id)
```

When I try and hit this method, I get the following error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult CreateServiceItem(Int32)' in 'API.Controllers.ItemsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters
```

Did some sort of syntax change between mvc2 and mvc3?

EDIT: Updated Information!

I think I found the culprit. I'm posting some data that's JSON data to the URL. My JSON object happens to look like this:

```
{ Id: null, OtherProperty: 'foo' }
```

MVC3 is using the Id from my JSON object rather than the ID specified in the URL. Is this behavior configurable?

EDIT 2: Reproducable example:

We use Ext in our application, so my example is with Ext, but I can reproduce it, this is in my /Views/Home/Index.aspx:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
  var w = new Ext.Window({
    title: 'Hi there',
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    items: [
      new Ext.Button({
        text: 'Click me',
        handler: function() {
          var obj = {
            Id: null,
            Text: 'Hi there'
          };
          Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/item/3/serviceitem',
            method: 'POST',
            jsonData: Ext.util.JSON.encode(obj),
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
            success: function(result, request) {
              console.log(result);
            },
            failure: function(result, request) {
              console.log(result);
            }
          });
        }
      })
]
  });

  w.show();
});
```

In my Global.asax, I have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Test",
  "{controller}/{id}/{subentity}",
  new { action = "Index" },
  new { id = @"\d+", subentity = "serviceitem" }
);
```

In my /Controllers/ItemController, I have this method:

```
[ActionName("Index")]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult CreateServiceItem(int id)
{
  string data;
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
  {
    data = sr.ReadToEnd();
  }
  return Json(new
  {
    DT = DateTime.Now,
    Id = id,
    PostedData = data
  });
}
```

When I hit the button, causing a POST to the controller w/ the JSON data specified, I get the same error as above. If I don't send the JSON data, it works (since MVC will use the URL part as the parameter to my method).

Here's a link to my repro solution zipped up: http://www.mediafire.com/?77881176saodnxp

Comment: Basically, I have the same problem as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334818/mvc-3-posting-content-type-application-json-action-method-arguments-loose-mappi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, nothing changed in this respect. It's the kind of questions for which I like to call *status no repro*.

Steps:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project using the default template
2. Add `ItemsController` to the project:

   ```
   public class ItemsController : Controller
   {
       [ActionName("Index")]
       [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
       public ActionResult CreateServiceItem(int id)
       {
           return Content(id.ToString());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Modify the route registration in `Application_Start` so that it looks like this:

   ```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapRoute(
         "Versioned API with Controller, ID, subentity",
         "api/{version}/{controller}/{id}/{subentity}",
         new { controller = "API", action = "Index" },
         new { id = @"\d+", subentity = "serviceitem|accessitem" }
       );

       routes.MapRoute(
           "Default",
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
   }
   ```
4. Modify `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` view so that it looks like this:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $.ajax({
           url: '/api/1.0/items/3/serviceitem',
           type: 'POST',
           success: function (result) {
               alert(result);
           }
       });
   </script>
   ```
5. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the project
6. As expected the default browser launches, an AJAX request is sent to the `CreateServiceItem` action of `Items` controller which returns the id=3 string and it is this string that gets alerted.

Conclusion: either you haven't shown your actual code or the problem is, as I like to say, in your TV.

---

UPDATE:

Now that you have posted a reproducible example I see what the problem is and how it is different than my test case. In my test case I performed the request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'item/3/serviceitem',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ model: { id: null, text: 'Hi there' } }),
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

In your request you are doing this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'item/3/serviceitem',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ id: null, text: 'Hi there' }),
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

There is no longer the model name variable. So there is a conflict when you try to invoke the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult CreateServiceItem(int id)
```

If the model is not wrapped in a proper object in your request, the model binder picks the value from the POST request first because it has precedence than the value of the url. It's how the model binder works: it first looks in POSTed data. In ASP.NET MVC 2 this was working fine because there was no `JsonValueProviderFactory` so there was no id parameter in the POST request. In ASP.NET MVC 3 this was introduced and now there is a value for it.

The workaround I would suggest you is to wrap your JSON in another object.

Comment: What if you post some JSONData along with your request?

Comment: @Jonas, ahhh, now you start talking about some JSON data. That kind of changes what you asked initially. You should have shown your code. Anyway, still works perfectly fine for me. Request `$.ajax({ url: '/api/1.0/items/3/serviceitem', type: 'POST', data: JSON.stringify({ model: { foo: 'bar'} }), contentType: 'application/json', success: function (result) { alert(result); } });` and controller action signature: `public ActionResult CreateServiceItem(int id, MyViewModel model)` with a view model: `public class MyViewModel { public string Foo { get; set; } }` => no problem whatsoever.

Comment: What happens if your JSON data contains a property called 'ID'?

Comment: @Jonas, still works perfectly fine for me. The id action parameter gets assigned `3` from the route and my view model Id property gets assigned the whatever value I give it in my `JSON.stringify` method. So really, if you have further questions, please show your code and explain your problems because as I said: status no repro.

Comment: but if your JSON data looks like this: {Id: null} does it still work?

Comment: @Jonas, of course that it works, you just need to ensure that you have defined your Id property on the view model as a nullable integer: `public int? Id { get; set; }`. Otherwise it would be kind of stupid to try to assign null to a non-nullable type and would of course lead to exceptions.

Comment: I don't want to use the data from JSON as the method parameter, I want to use the data from the URL. Is that something I can configure?

Comment: @Jonas with `public ActionResult CreateServiceItem(int id)` and `url: '/api/1.0/items/3/serviceitem'` in your AJAX call you get `id=3` from te no matter what JSON request you send. I really don't understand what your problem is, what your code looks like, how you are invoking the controller action. Without this information I really don't see how I can help you any further.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4449/discussion-between-jonas-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: that's what I'm saying, is in my case, I don't. With this JSON data: {"ID":null,"ItemID":3,"DurationType":1,"DurationValue":15,"RedemptionGLCode":"","StaffRequired":false,"Schedulable":true,"AlertAtCheckin":false,"RedemptionLocationType":2,"Units":1} and the url 'api/1.0/items/3/serviceitem', I get the error specified above.

Comment: @Jonas, is the ID property of your view model defined as a nullable integer?

Comment: No, it's not, and nor do I want it to be.

Comment: @Jonas, well then you have a problem. A serious problem. You are trying to assign null to a non-nullable type. I don't know what to say. Oh and by the way ASP.NET MVC 2 didn't have anything built-in to bind JSON requests. So when you talk about some broken functionality, well, such functionality actually never existed in ASP.NET MVC 2. The `JsonValueProviderFactory` was introduced in ASP.NET MVC 3. So maybe you wrote some custom code or something to bind JSON requests to view models or something.

Comment: (headdesk) I don't want to assign null to a non-nullable type :D My URL is not /items/NULL/serviceitem, it's /items/3/serviceitem. I think the fix we've come up w/ is to remove that JsonValueProviderFactory on app startup.

Comment: @Jonas, what's with `{"ID":null, ...}` in your JSON request then? Looks like you trying to assign `null` to the `ID` property of your view model.

Comment: We're not really using a View model. Inside the controller method, we have code like this:  var Foo = SomeMethodThatReadsJSONFromThePostAndDeserializesIt(); So we don't have the "viewmodel" per se in the method signature.

Comment: @Jonas, there shouldn't be a problem with invoking the controller action then. The problem will be on the `SomeMethodThatReadsJSONFromThePostAndDeserializesIt` line. I think this will be the last comment I will write on this thread. I have shown you a working example with both JSON request and without JSON request. If you want to me to continue helping with this I would expect you updating your question and show your actual code and explaining what problems you are encountering with it.

Comment: I agree there shouldn't be, but there is :D As I said, our workaround was to remove the JsonValueProviderFactory on app_start:    var jsonFact = ValueProviderFactories.Factories.OfType<JsonValueProviderFactory>().FirstOrDefault();
   if (jsonFact != null)
    ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Remove(jsonFact);

Comment: I've edited the question to add in reproducible steps as well as a link to a .zip containing a sample project where this is reproduced.

Comment: @Jonas, perfect. Now that you have shown a full example it is clear where the problem comes from. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update...is there a way to change the order of precedence in this case?

Comment: Funny, how I had exactly the same problem. Wrapping the JSON data into an object with the parameter name as a key should work. Thanks!